# HDFS: FileSystem.exists(path) return false on existing resource?

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I am having in a locally running Hadoop HDFS (my work station is name/data node) difficulties to access files.

In my HDFS I have a file located in the folder `"/huser/data.txt"`
I can confirm with `hdfs dfs -ls /huser` that the file exists.

I create the FileSystem by calling `FileSystem.get(uri, config)`, uri being `hdfs://localhost:9000` 
If I call the exist method of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` I get always a `false` as return value.

I tried various parameter combinations, but I am wondering what I am doing wrong:

```
fs.exists(new Path("hdfs:/huser/data.txt")) 
fs.exists(new Path("hdfs://huser/data.txt"))
```

both don't work.

I tried also using a MiniDFSCluster to provide a minimal working example, but unfortunately it works there. I seem to have an issue with a live HDFS and accessing the files (Hadoop 2.6).

Comment: Do you remember what was the issue? I am facing the same issue. My code ran successfully before 2 days. but now it returns false. I did nt made any change to my code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a bit late but i stumpled upon your question while googling. For anyone having this issue, the solution is to not include hdfs in your path

```
fs.exists(new Path("/huser/data.txt)
```

This should work